# I sublet my flat. What should I put when scholarships ask me for the owner's contact information?

Tags: rental-property, spain

I'm a student, and I've been living in a rental flat for a week. As it happens, some scholarships ask me to give details about my contract terms. Everything is all right so far, but the person that contacted us is not the real owner of the flat, but a guy who rents from the real owner.

Will there be any problem at all if I give the information of my "contract?" If there is, what can I do?

Comment: Where are you located geographically? I wouldn't think scholarships would care if you sublet an apartment. I imagine you could just put whatever information is in your contract. If you actually signed a rental contract (and aren't just living "off the radar"), I don't see why it would be a problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "off the radar"?
and im in spain

Comment: I mean, you don't have a formal contract that you signed, with *anyone* (owner or otherwise), you just pay a friend some amount of money in an informal arrangement and borrow a room for a week or so. Do you actually have a contract, or you just staying with friends for a bit?

Comment: we do have a paper signed by both parts with the agreements, but not sure if it has any legal valor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have a legitimate signed agreement with the person who is legitimately renting and has a contract with the owners, you are in dealings with the person from whom you sublet the place. Therefore for all intents and purposes they are your landlord. You would provide their information, how much you are paying them, and so on - basically as if they are the landlord because legally they are. As for your scholarships that will make no difference. Since you renting, paying and its legit (meaning not a favor). So you are good and covered to use that information.